# word-embendding: Convert supervised model into unsupervised model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, unsupervised-learning, fasttext

I'm wanna to load an pre-trained embendding to initalize my own unsupervise FastText model and retrain with my dataset.

The trained embendding file I have loads fine with `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model.txt')`. But when I try:
`FastText.load_fasttext_format('model.txt')` I get: `NotImplementedError: Supervised fastText models are not supported`.

Is there any way to convert supervised KeyedVectors to unsupervised FastText? And if possible, is it a bad idea?

I know that has an great difference between supervised and unsupervised models. But I really wanna try use/convert this and retrain it. I'm not finding a trained unsupervised model to load for my case (it's a portuguese dataset), and the best model I find [is that](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/index.php/repositorio-de-word-embeddings-do-nilc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `model.txt` file loads OK with `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('model.txt')`, then that's just a simple set of word-vectors. (That is, not a 'supervised' model.)

However, Gensim's `FastText` doesn't support preloading a simple set of vectors for further training - for continued training, it needs a full `FastText` model, either from Facebook's binary format, or a prior Gensim `FastText` model `.save()`.

(That trying to load a plain-vectors file generates that error suggests the `load_fasttext_format()` method is momentarily mis-interpreting it as some other kind of binary FastText model it doesn't support.)

*Update after comment below:*

Of course you *can* mutate a model however you like, including ways not officially supported by Gensim. Whether that's helpful is another matter.

You can create an FT model with a compatible/overlapping vocabulary, load old word-vectors separately, then copy each prior vector over to replace the corresponding (randomly-initialized) vectors in the new model. (Note that the property to affect further training is actually `ftModel.wv.vectors_vocab` trained-up full-word vectors, *not* the `.vectors` which is composited from full-words & ngrams,)

But the tradeoffs of such an ad-hoc strategy are many. The ngrams would still start random. Taking some prior model's just-word vectors isn't quite the same as a FastText model's full-words-to-be-later-mixed-with-ngrams.

You'd want to make sure your new model's sense of word-frequencies is meaningful, as those affect further training - but that data *isn't* usually available with a plain-text prior word-vector set. (You could plausibly synthesize a good-enough set of frequencies by assuming a Zipf distribution.)

Your further training might get a "running start" from such initialization - but that wouldn't necessarily mean the end-vectors remain comparable to the starting ones. (All positions may be arbitrarily changed by the volume of newer training, progressively diluting away most of the prior influence.)

So: you'd be in an improvised/experimental setup, somewhat far from usual FastText practices and thus where you'd want to re-verify lots of assumptions, and rigorously evaluate if those extra steps/approximations are actually improving things.

Comment: I understand. But if I create a new FastText model,  could I overwrite the vectors values with those trained values? I tryed to do something like this with `ftModel.wv.__seitem__(word, updatedVector)` but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Indeed - se updated answer for considerations.